# Rails 4 - Redirect to anchor section of a page after login

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

Rails 4.2.4 - When I clicked on a link from an email it will ask for login. After logged in, it will redirect to a proper page but in that page, many sections are there. How can I redirect to particular section?

In controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:return_to] || root_url
end
```

`user_new_path(:anchor=>'profile_pic')` is the link.

In views:

```
<div id='other_details'>
  ...
</div>
<div id='profile_pic'>
  ...
</div>
```

How can I solve this redirect issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting `user_new_path(:anchor=>'profile_pic')` in the `after_sign_in_path_for` method?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it but same issue is there. It will not redirect to `profile_pic` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
user_new_path + '#profile_pic'
```

in after_sign_in_path_for method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned above, its working fine. But new issue occurs, when user login(normally) it should go to home page right now it always leads to profile page only.

Comment: I have fixed this issue using your method (as mentioned above) by checking some conditions.